# How to pass a div element as a parameter to an MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

how can i pass a `<div>Hello World</div>` using jQuerys `$.post()` function to an MVC controller like `public JsonResult GetDiv(string element)`
I've tried `encodeURL()` on the client but I keep getting an Internal Server Error(500)...i'm basically trying to save HTML code to SQL Server. Thanks.

Comment: if you get 500... so the path in your route doesn't exist... I guess so your controller method isn't exposed to be called

Comment: @sonic i put a break point on the function, it only gets invoked when im not passing the html but as soon as i try to pass a param(the div), i get err 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you'll need to decorate the specific property that you are attempting to pass with the [`[AllowHtml]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) attribute as seen below on the property that you are attempting to use HTML for:

```
public class HtmlContent 
{
    [AllowHtml] 
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And then simply bind the to that property within your Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult GetDiv(HtmlContent element) 
{ 
     // Access your element here
     var html = element.Content;

     // Save to the database
}
```

This will let .NET know that this string is expected to contain HTML content, which it may otherwise see as potentially malicious content and reject (similar to the 500 error that you are experiencing).

Comment: var html = element.Content; did not work, Content is not recognized...is HtmlContent under using System.Net.Http; ?

Comment: No - that was just an example of a custom wrapper class. I believe the `[AllowHtml]` attribute requires a property to decorate (i.e. it can't be inlined via something like `public JsonResult GetDiv([AllowHtml] string content) { ... }`).

Answer (score 0):

On parent element of div, call innerHTML, this will return the HTML as a string, which you can then post.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more details?
Where is your controller running?
Is there any specification of your Controller youre posting data to?

In order to get the HTML code of your jQuery div use the `.html()` function - [link](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

The [post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function works as follows:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

The second argument must be a string or a plain object. Therefore using the html()-Function should work.

Here is a fiddle I made (basicly a copy pasta of the jsfiddle.net [echo](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests) demo + jquery post demo): https://jsfiddle.net/vyrdp7uo/